# Table doesn't respond to second jQuery request

Tags: php, jquery, html, html-table

My PHP script generates a table with rows which can optionally be edited or deleted. There is also a possibility to create a new Row. The PHP is activated through jQuery Events.

Now all works well, I can edit delete and create an Item. After each action which makes use of the PHP script the HTML table gets updated.

But when I try after an Event to do an action again the HTML Table doesn't get updated though in the background the PHP script makes an entry into the database.

Does someone of you know why my HTML Table doesn't update itself when I trigger a second event?

Here is the Script:

**PHP**

```
<?php
  require_once "../../includes/constants.php";
  // Connect to the database as necessary
  $dbh = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD)
    or die ("Unaable to connnect to MySQL");

  $selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$dbh)
    or die("Could not select printerweb");

   $action = $_POST['action'];
   $name = $_POST['name'];
   $id = $_POST['id'];

    if($action == "new")
      {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `place` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (NULL, '$name')");
      }
    elseif($action == "edit")
      {
        mysql_query("UPDATE `place` SET `name` = '$name' WHERE `id` = '$id'");        
      }
    elseif($action == "delete")
      {
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM place WHERE id = '$id'");
      }

    echo "<table><tbody>";
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM place");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo "<tr><td id=".$row["id"]." class=inputfield_td><input class=inputfield_place type=text value=".$row["name"]." /></td><td class=place_name>".$row["name"]."</td><td class=edit>edit</td><td class=cancel>cancel</td><td class=delete>delete</td><td class=save>SAVE</td></tr> \n";
    }
    echo "</tbody>";
    echo "</table>";
    echo "<input type=text class=inputfield_visible />";
    echo "<button class=new>Neu</button>";
?>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
  $.ajax({
  url: "place/place_list.php",
  cache: false,
  success: function (html){
    $("#place_container").append(html);
      }
  });
  $(".edit").live("click", function() {
    $(this).css("display","none").prevAll(".place_name").css("display","none").prevAll(".inputfield_td").css("display","block").nextAll(".cancel").css("display","block").nextAll(".save").css("display","block").prevAll(".inputfield_td").css("display","block");
  });
  $(".cancel").live("click", function() {
    myvariable5 = $(this).prevAll(".place_name").html();
    $(this).css("display","none").prevAll(".edit").css("display","block").prevAll(".place_name").css("display","block").prevAll(".inputfield_td").css("display","none").nextAll(".save").css("display","none").siblings().find("input[type=text]").val(myvariable5);
  });
  $(".save").live("click", function() {
    var myvariable1 = $(this).siblings().find("input[type=text]").val();
    var myvariable2 = $(this).prevAll("td:last").attr("id");
    $(this).css("display","none").prevAll(".cancel").css("display","none").prevAll(".edit").css("display","block").prevAll(".place_name").css("display","block").prevAll(".inputfield_td").css("display","none");
    $.post("place/place_list.php", {action: "edit", name: ""+myvariable1+"", id: ""+myvariable2+""}, function (html){$("#place_container").replaceWith(html);});
  });
  $(".delete").live("click", function() {
    var myvariable3 = $(this).prevAll("td:last").attr("id");
    $.post("place/place_list.php", {action: "delete", id: ""+myvariable3+""}, function (html){$("#place_container").replaceWith(html);});
  });
  $(".new").live("click", function() {
    var myvariable4 = $(this).prevAll("input[type=text]").val();
    $.post("place/place_list.php", {action: "new", name: ""+myvariable4+""}, function (html){$("#place_container").replaceWith(html);});
  });
});
```

Comment: have you tried debugging your code with Firebug?

Comment: You should also surround your parameter values with single quotes (i.e. class='inputfield_td', not class=inputfield_td)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I know. You do **replaceWith** instead of **append**, so your DIV with ID `#place_container` disappears after the first operation (you are left with only a table in your page), and of course jQuery does not find it and is unable to refresh it with new content from the second operation.

Just use append or, better yet, [html](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/html#val) methods.

Comment: Wait... now somehow it's generating 4 times the same row in the HTML table and the database?

Comment: When I change to a specific UI Tab and go back then this Error appears, changing to other Tabs won't generate this Problem.

Comment: Tabs? What tabs? You should take some time to trace your code step by step, it is most likely another logic fault.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldnt you replace the complete table ?

```
$("#place_container").html(html);
```

Comment: My container isn't filled with content at the initiation point of the JS so I don't think it would matter if the content is appended?

Comment: And what about the second, third, nth request?

Comment: The nth request will be replaced through the replaceWith request?

Comment: Got it working! I didn't know that the replaceWith request doesn't replace all content

Comment: No, didn't get it working somehow it's generating 4 times the same row in the HTML and database